# How to measure trace impedance?

Tags: pcb, impedance, multiplexer, trace

I have seen that trace impedances in PCB's are maintained 50 ohm & so on. How to measure this impedance using a simple multimeter?

Comment: You can get fairly close by calculation though. Unless you're laying out a gigabit PCB, you will probably get by with the predicted impedance. And unless you have a long track, the parasitic effects of corners, pads, vias etc will dominate.

Answer (score 9):

There is no* way to measure trace impedance with a simple multimeter.

Measuring trace impedance requires, at minimum, an oscilloscope and an impulse generator of some sort. [Here's](http://www.edn.com/electronics-blogs/benchtalk/4431974/Quick---dirty-cable-length---impedance-measurement) an article about how you can measure the impedance of a cable (or PCB) with a signal generator.

Doing "Proper" impedance measurements requires a special tool, called a [network analyzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_analyzer_(electrical)).

<sub>* No *reasonable* way, in any event. There may be ways to abuse a **specific** model of meter in a *specific* manner to get a approximate result, but it won't be generalizable.</sub>

Comment: @Connor_Wolf I think you should explain how to use a network analyzer to measure characteristic impedance of a PCB trace in the lab? It's not that easy to do for short structures. I feel a TDR is much easier to use (but be really careful with ESD).

Answer (score 6):

You should use a TDR (time domain reflectometer) or a Lecroy Sparq which is a cross between a network analyzer and a TDR.  You can also use controlled impedance with your board house and specify to them what the impedance is.  Then demand a test coupon and measurement results.

As a poor mans approach you can sort of build your own TDR with your oscilloscope.   But you need a fast edge / pulse source, probably in the ps range depending on how long your traces are.   Preferably with an output impedance close to your trace.  I once used a analog devices high speed opamp with ps rise on the output for this.

Anyway input the fast pulse into your trace ( with no termination) and if you measure with your scope at the source you should see the reflection from the unterminated edge come back.

Then add a termination resistor at the far end of the trace that you think matches the impedance.  When you get it right no more reflection :)

A little tricky but doable if you can't afford the test gear.

Comment: Oh I should add you'll need a scope with enough bandwidth and sample rate to see the ps rise time :)