# Why is it not possible to measure PCB trace characteristic impedance using a multimeter?

Tags: pcb, impedance, measurement, multimeter, trace

I was looking into StackExchange posts for PCB trace impedance measurement.

[How to measure trace impedance?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/151132/how-to-measure-trace-impedance)

This posts clearly explains what the methods to be used for trace impedance measurement are.

I searched in many places to find out why we can't use a multimeter for trace impedance measurement, but I did not find a proper answer.

Can you please explain why multimeters are not used for trace impedance measurements?

Comment: The simple answer is that it is just not possible. Characteristic impedance is a vastly different thing from resistance, if that's what you were thinking of.

Comment: okay trace impedance contains R,C and L components that is why it is not possible using a multimeter.correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You will likely never get enough precision in any L or C measurements of PCB traces using only a multimeter, to get any usable results. The inductance and capacitance is too low for any standard multimeter to measure accurately.

Comment: You can use a multimeter to measure trace impedance, provided the trace is very, very, very long!  Otherwise the low bandwidth on your multimeter means that the pulse it injects will reach steady state and converge to the resistance of the trace+load before the read out is finished.

Comment: @user1850479 given the typical 0.5s integration time it could work for a trace long 100km, maybe. Assuming that the multimeter could drive such a wire (and only for the first reading)

Comment: Not a useful method, but it is helpful to understand that the reason a multimeter can't measure impedance in practice is that for such a low bandwidth device, no practical wire is a transmission line, so you always get the lumped element result. But if you built a fast enough multimeter for the length of trace you wanted to measure, you could in fact measure 50 ohms on a 50 ohm trace, at least for some picoseconds.  Then the signal would reach the other end and (if not 50 ohm terminated), reflect and the reflection will screw up your impedance measurement.

Comment: The parasitic capacitance and inductance of the meter's probes would dwarf the capacitance and inductance of the thing you are trying to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing impedance and resistance.

A multimeter measures *resistance*: it puts a known voltage and measure the current (the other way works, too) and gives you the resistance i.e. the DC impedance

For measuring *impedance* the method is more or less the same but you do it with an AC signal (a sinusoid); what you measure is the amplitude and the phase of the current so it's a complex quantity.

It is also varying with frequency: in fact the equipment used for low frequencies (impedance meters/analyzers) are quite different that those for high frequencies.

For PCB measurement you are usually interested in impedance at high frequencies (since at low frequency a PCB is small enough to not pose a problem). You need a VNA for that which is probably the single most expensive piece of electronic test equipment (I've seen *whole rooms* built for that kind of testing).

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: A slow multimeter will fail, a fast one will measure it fine.

It *is* possible to measure trace impedance using a multimeter/voltmeter:

The main problem with sluggish handheld multimeters is that they are too slow to measure the transient time during which the instantaneous *resistance* of the line is equal to its characteristic impedance.

If you take a very long transmission line that goes all the way to the moon, has an open end and negligible series losses, then you will measure its characteristic impedance via a resistance measure with a standard multimeter, but only during the first second or so. After that, the multimeter will read an open circuit.

Now for practical length transmission lines such as cables of a few meter length: Propagation delay is only some 10s of ns for such lines. If you have a multimeter with a fast enough sample rate (>1 GS/s) you sure can measure the line impedance. Probably you will have to measure a few transients and average the result if you want a figure that is precise to 1 Ohm or something. It is only that fast sampling measurement devices with GS/s sample rates often don't go by the name multimeter, but have some other fancy name (e.g. oscilloscope).

### How the measurement works:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fesA1g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

1. Connect a constant voltage source \$V_0\$ to you multimeter. It should have a low output impedance out to several GHz. I.e. it should be buffered with a small array of ceramic caps. Put a resistor of e.g. 100 Ohm in series with the voltage source. The voltmeter will read \$V_0\$.
2. When the switch closes, during the propagation delay you will form a voltage divider with R1 and the line impedance. The Voltmeter will record a momentary drop . It is this reduced voltage level \$V_{drop}\$ which gives you the line impedance \$Z_0\$ as \$R1 \cdot \frac{V_{drop}}{V_0-V_{drop}}\$.
3. After a roundtrip time, the travelling signal returns and raises the voltmeter reading to near \$V_0\$. It will be exactly \$V_0\$ when R1 is equal to the line impedance or higher/lower if there is some mismatch. Over time - after several roundtrips - the voltage reading will anyway equalize at \$V_0\$.

Answer (score 2):

The multimeter is not fast enough. In order to measure trace impedance you have to measure the impedance before the reflection comes back from the far end of the trace. You only have a few hundred picoseconds to make the measurement.

But if you had a really long trace on a giant circuit board bigger than earth, then you could use a multimeter to measure trace impedance.

Or you could design a special, super fast device that can measure the impedance of normal traces before the reflection comes back from the far end. But this special super fast device would be very similar to an oscilloscope.

There is also something called time domain reflectometry (TDR) which you could maybe use as a search term in your favorite search engine if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

> *Why is it not possible to measure PCB trace characteristic impedance
> using a multimeter?*

You can but, the multimeter's name changes to [time domain reflectometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-domain_reflectometer): -

[image]

It's generally the same sort of size as a multimeter and, is usually portable and battery powered.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a low cost way to estimate trace impedance, use a ruler. Measure the width of the trace, and the thickness of the substrate. Then enter those two, together with the substrate dielectric constant into one of the online trace impedance calculators. Typically a trace twice as wide as the substrate is thick will give you about 50Ω on FR4. It doesn't scale linearly.

Unfortunately, a multimeter measures ohms as DC volts / DC current, and takes about a second to read. If you had a transmission line 3x10^8 metres long, you might just get a reading in if you were quick. You'd need a superconducting line for its resistance not to swamp the reading.

To measure transmission lines of human-scale length, you need response times in the nano seconds, or frequencies in the GHz.

Answer (score 1):

I wholeheartedly recommend you read the [Chapter 14 - Transmission Lines: A 50 Ohm Cable?](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-14/50-ohm-cable/) on Allaboutcircuits. It will drive the main concepts home and clear up all that is usually confusing for people who first encounter them.

##### Cliffhanger:

> I was mystified by the “50 ohms” label on this coaxial cable. How
> could two conductors, insulated from each other by a relatively thick
> layer of plastic, have 50 ohms of resistance between them?
>
> Measuring the resistance between the outer and inner conductors with
> my ohmmeter, I found it to be infinite (open-circuit), just as I would
> have expected from the two insulated conductors.
>
> Measuring each of the two conductors’ resistances from one end of the
> cable to the other indicated nearly zero ohms of resistance: again,
> exactly what I would have expected from continuous, unbroken lengths
> of wire...